# emacsのauto-completeで１文字からパスを補完する方法

Tags: emacs, elisp

emacsでauto-complete.elを利用しています。C-x C-fなどで新しく開くファイルのパスを入力する際、ミニバッファに

/

と表示されているとします。たとえば/usr以下にあるファイルを開くとすると、uを入力して

/u

としてTABキーを押しますが、何故か

/run/

と補完されてしまいます。
usと２文字以上入力すれば意図通りに/usr/と補完されます。

設定は以下のとおりです。

```
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(ac-config-default)
(add-to-list 'ac-modes 'text-mode)

(中略)

(setq ac-auto-start 1)
(setq ac-use-menu-map t)
(setq ac-use-fuzzy t)
```

１文字から正しく補完させる方法はありませんでしょうか。よろしくお願いします。

Comment: そちらでお使いの Emacs と auto-complete のバージョンについて教えていただけますか。こちらでは Emacs 25.1 + auto-complete 1.5.0 を使用しているのですが、`/run` ディレクトリがあっても `/usr` に補完されます。

Comment: お返事が大変遅れまして申し訳ありません。Emacs 24.4.1 + auto-complete 1.5.0 を使用しております。よろしく願いいたしします。